# Is there a way to enumerate all the static functions in a class?

Tags: c#, .net, static, ienumerable, xamarin.forms

I have a class with lots of static methods, which I am using it as a sort of style sheet.

You give one of its methods a Label and it sets a bunch of the label properties such as color, font family and font size.

I want to create a page where you can view all the different Label styles so I would like to enumerate these static methods so I can apply each one to a label.

Is this possible? Is there a better way to template object properties?

```
public static class Palette
{

    public static class LabelStyle
    {

        public static void H3 (ref Label label)
        {
            label.TextColor     = Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
            label.FontFamily    = "Myriad";
            label.FontSize      = 14;
        }

        public static void H4 (ref Label label)
        {
            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS) 
            {
                label.FontFamily = Device.OnPlatform ("Myriad Pro", null, null);
            } 
            else
            {
                label.FontFamily = "Myriad";
            }

            label.TextColor     = Color.BlueBlack;
            label.FontSize      = 14;
        }

        ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[**Reflection**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) is the key word here.

```
typeof(Palette.LabelStyle).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static)
```

It can also be used for various similar purposes.

You may have to choose appropriate binding flags. In this example `BindingFlags.Static` is there to enumerate static methods. You need another binding flag for non-public ones. That would be:

```
BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic
```

*for example.*

Comment: Depending on context, you may need `typeof(Palette.LabelStyle)`.

Comment: You're right, @RichardSchneider, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why but my compiler is telling me those methods don't exist, ` Error CS1061: Type System.Type does not contain a definition for GetMethods and no extension method GetMethods of type System.Type could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? `

Comment: Might be something to do with Xamarin's version of .Net